# Comparing a set of coordinates (strokes?) for a percentage difference

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates, distance, percentage

I have 2 paths A and B.

For example:

```
A = {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)}
B = {(2,2), (3,3), (5,5), (6,7)}
```

Each pair of elements is a line, starting at the element before it.
The beginning element is the start of the stroke, and the ending element is the end of the stroke.

I want to compare A and B for similarity, and in the end get a percentage accuracy.

I have done some research already and found references to Hausdorff Distance and Frechet Distance but I cannot figure out how to get these to do what I want them to do.

Thank you!

(The language I am looking to code this in, is Java if any libraries exist for this problem, that would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: *"but I cannot figure out how to get these to do what I want them to do"* -- always best to show your attempts with your question and to elaborate on the problems you're having with your attempts.

Comment: I have tried reading their articles on wikipedia, but from that I have not figured out what to do, or how it's meant to be used.

Comment: This sounds more like a statistics question than a programming question.  If you want to write code for a Hausdorff Distance, for example, please try writing the code and then ask for help if you get stuck, but don't ask us how to use a measurement like that, or how good it is, because most of us won't know.  The folks at math.stackexchange.com might know, though.